# Creating a Mac-bootable USB stick (with Lubuntu installer) using Lubuntu

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, live-usb, mac, macbook-air

I want to use Ubuntu tools (preferable command line tools) to create  a USB with the Lubuntu 16.04 installer, which is bootable on a MacBook Air.

How do I do this?

**Background:** I have a `MacBookAir4,2` which is currently running Lubuntu LTS 14.04, and now I want to upgrade it to Lubuntu LTS 16.04. As a plan B, if this upgrade fails, I wish to prepare a USB stick which I can use to install Lubuntu from scratch.

I have found numerous instructions on how to produce a Mac-bootable USB stick from *OSX*, but I don't own a machine running OSX. The only machine I have available is running Lubuntu (but happens to be Mac hardware).

Comment: I have no Mac computer, but from what I have read a standard cloned USB boot drive for a PC will work in a Mac computer too. Cloning from the iso file (with Lubuntu) can be done in Lubuntu using **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or **mkusb**. Disks is already there, and you can install mkusb according to this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb ; You can run `mkusb-dus` and `mkusb-nox` in text mode, if you wish. Both 'wrap a security belt' around `dd`.

Comment: Upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS is a risky operation, so you should backup everything, that you cannot afford to lose before doing it. This kind of upgrading can be done without any iso file or external drive if you have a good (wired) internet connection. Use the command line `sudo do-release-upgrade`. See `man do-release-upgrade` for details.

Answer (score 1):

I was under the mistaken impression that a USB stick required some kind of special treatment to become bootable on Mac hardware.

I actually solved this by preparing the USB stick in the same way as I would've done for an ordinary Linux machine.

I fetched the relevant ISO, and wrote it the a USB using `dd`, like so:

```
dd if=lubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-i386.iso of=/dev/sdd bs=4M && sync
```

After rebooting I held down the `Alt` key (just like you're supposed to for a Mac) to reach the boot menu, and then selected the USB stick.

Thereafter the machine booted from the USB stick.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you, and thanks for sharing your solution :-) But I will add a warning: `dd` is a powerful but also dangerous tool. It does what you tell it to do without questions. If you tell it to wipe the family pictures, it will do it, and it is a minor typing error away. It is a good idea to use a cloning tool with a final checkpoint, where you can double-check, that you will be writing  to the correct target device (the USB pendrive) and not the internal drive.